# Any alternative for natsort in PHP, which wont fail when processing alphanumeric characters with zeros

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is there any alternative for natsort which can  process an array like this

```
array('IMG0001.jpg','IMG00010.jpg','IMG0002.jpg','IMG000100.jpg','IMG00090.jpg','IMG00020.jpg','IMG000200.jpg')
```

expected output is

```
array('IMG0001.jpg','IMG0002.jpg','IMG00010.jpg','IMG00020.jpg','IMG00090.jpg','IMG000100.jpg','IMG000200.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
$x = ['IMG0001.jpg','IMG00010.jpg','IMG0002.jpg','IMG000100.jpg',
      'IMG00090.jpg','IMG00020.jpg','IMG000200.jpg'];

function removeLeadingZeros($x) {
    return preg_replace('!([^\d]+)0+!', '\\1', $x);
}

usort($x, function ($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp(removeLeadingZeros($a), removeLeadingZeros($b));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$arr=array('IMG0001.jpg','IMG00010.jpg','IMG0002.jpg','IMG000100.jpg','IMG00090.jpg','IMG00020.jpg','IMG000200.jpg');
sort($arr, SORT_NATURAL );// also sort($arr, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE) for case sensitive sorting
```

Comment: Are you tried your solution? It returns items in wrong order on PHP 5.5.

Comment: Failed at my end. I tried with this array Array([0] => IMG000106.jpg,    [1] => IMG00031.jpg,    [2] => IMG000203.jpg,    [3] => IMG000278.jpg,    [4] => IMG000183.jpg,    [5] => IMG00018.jpg,    [6] => IMG000166.jpg,    [7] => IMG000176.jpg,    [8] => IMG00029.jpg,    [9] => IMG000284.jpg,    [10] => IMG000187.jpg,    [11] => IMG000145.jpg,    [12] => IMG000256.jpg,    [13] => IMG00090.jpg,    [14] => IMG00089.jpg,    [15] => IMG00011.jpg,    [16] => IMG0005.jpg,    [17] => IMG00036.jpg,    [18] => IMG000295.jpg,    [19] => IMG00042.jpg,    [20] => IMG000260.jpg,...)

Comment: PHP Version on server is 5.3.19